# Automatically move from column D back to A after data input

Tags: excel, vba, barcode

I need to make it so when a user enters data (scans a barcode) into column D it will automatically move them back to column A so they can start over.

Comment: Do you mean it will select the cell in the same row or in the next row of column `A`?

Comment: It would be the next row, my apologies. So when data is entered in cell D1, it will move the cursor not the data back to A2. This way they don't need to do any clicking in the sheet and the whole system is just a series of scans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Select Cell in Next Row

- This code needs to be copied to the sheet module, e.g. `Sheet1`, of the worksheet where it should be applied, not in a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "D2"
    Const DESTINATION_COLUMN_STRING As String = "A"
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    With Me.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        If Intersect(srg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End With
    
    Me.Cells(Target.Row + 1, DESTINATION_COLUMN_STRING).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: That whole Intersect logic seems a bit redundant.   Why not  just `If Target.Column = 4 Then ... .Select`?

Comment: @chris neilsen: It is nitpicking, of course. If the data starts in row 2 (`D2`), as in this example, I wouldn't want it to run for row 1 (`D1`). OP's data could start in row 11, so why should it run for rows 1 to 10 (`D1:D10`)? I mean, we're talking about microseconds here, right? Of course, in this 'harmless' case, there is no harm done either way.

Comment: No offense intended,  just trying to suggest cleaner code.

Comment: @chris neilsen: No offense taken. I guess you're right. The readability was destroyed 
 already when I introduced the constants. It's too complicated for such a simple task.  Thanks for your input, it is always welcome and doesn't lack objectivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event `Worksheet_Change`

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Column = 4 Then
           ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unclear in my question. I need this to only move the cursor back to column A on the next row.

Comment: OK, i edit my answer, you can try it.